# grep match is too close from filename

Tags: awk, grep, sign

I'm using `grep` to find values. However, when the value has a minus sign the grep match result is too close from the filename.

Here is the code to find the value:

```
grep -r "something" * | sort | awk '{print $2}')
```

This didn’t work. Then I used:

```
grep -r "something" * | sort
```

The output for this command is:

```
filename1:-1.0 "other line contents"  
filename2:-1.0 "other line contents"  
filename3: 1.0 "other line contents"  
filename4: 1.0 "other line contents"
```

I need to sort the files by name.

How can I increase the space after the `"filename:"`? Or there is another way?

Comment: `sort -t: -k1 -o file file` use the ':' as a delimiter to sort by field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `cut`:

```
grep -r "something" * | sort | cut -d: -f2-
```

`cut -d: -f2-` *cuts* on `:` and give you all the fields starting from the second one.

For example `echo foo:bar:qux | cut -d: -f2-` gives `bar:qux`. In your case it’ll remove the filename and give you the rest.